# htaccess redirect with negated conditions

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Simple redirect in `.htaccess` works:

```
#Redirect 302 / https://domain.toberedirected.com
```

But the conditional one doesn't. I want that if the remote user IP address is in the list then ignore the redirect and if not in the list, then make 302 redirect to another domain.

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.1.1.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=2.2.2.2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=3.3.3.3 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=4.4.4.4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://domain.toberedirected.com" [L]
```

But the code redirects anyway is my IP in the list or not?

Comment: What is the intended redirect? From what to what? The two rules (`Redirect` and `RewriteRule`) are performing different redirects. The `Redirect` is redirecting to the same URL-path on the target domain, whilst the `RewriteRule` is redirecting everything to the homepage only (although you are missing the trailing slash) - what is the intention?

Comment: Just want to ask if you are wanting to redirect temporarily or permanently? Status code `302 Found` "means that the URI of requested resource has been changed _temporarily_. Further changes in the URI might be made in the future" and `301 Moved Permanently` "The URL of the requested resource has been changed permanently."
[HTTP response status codes - Redirection messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages) and [RewriteRule Flags - R|redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.1.1.1 [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=2.2.2.2 [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=3.3.3.3 [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=4.4.4.4
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://domain.toberedirected.com" [L]
> ```

You have the logic wrong... you should be (implicitly) AND'ing the *negated* conditions, not OR'ing them. If you `OR` them then one of the conditions will always be successful (the REMOTE_ADDR will always *not* be one of the stated IP addresses since it can not be all of them) and so the group of OR'd conditions will always be successful and the redirect will always occur.

"AND" is the default, so you should simply remove the flags argument on these conditions. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.1.1.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=2.2.2.2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=3.3.3.3
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=4.4.4.4
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.toberedirected.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It now reads... if the REMOTE_ADDR is *not* `1.1.1.1` AND is *not* `2.2.2.2` AND is *not* `3.3.3.3` AND is *not* `4.4.4.4` then redirect...

You should really be explicit with the redirect and include the `R` flag.

Note sure of the intention of the redirect, but I included the `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string in order to redirect to the same URL-path on the target. (Otherwise, why capture the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*?) This then behaves the same as the earlier `Redirect` directive you had (which is "prefix-matching").

---

If, however, you wanted to redirect everything to the homepage on the target domain (as your original `RewriteRule` would have done) then change the `RewriteRule` directive like so:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.toberedirected.com/ [R,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (`^`) does not match/capture anything, but is successful for everything. And the inclusion of the trailing slash after the hostname in the *substitution* string.

However, this many-to-one redirect is generally not good for SEO/UX since search engines are likely to see it as a soft-404 and users end up on a page they are not expecting and *bounce*.

---

**UPDATE:** I've just noticed you had previously tagged the question "wordpress". If this is WordPress then the above redirect must go at the very top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker).

Comment: Big thanks! It worked. Logic needs to be further learned.